# Does System.Timers.Timer.Stop() restart the interval countdown?

Tags: c#, timer

```
using System.Timers;

var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Start();

// Wait for 500

timer.Stop();
timer.Start();
```

Here will my interval have 500 left to run or 1000?

Comment: 1000. It will start from the beginning

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short question, short answer. Your timer will start with a fresh interval of 1000ms after it has been stopped. See also [MSDN: `System.Timers.Timer.Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx)